Помогите, где я допустил ошибку?
Числа следует выводить через пробел. Все числа целые.
Дан массив, состоящий из целых чисел. Нумерация элементов начинается с 0. Нужно написать программу, которая выведет элементы массива, номера которых четны (0, 2, 4...).
Входные данные:
Сначала задано число N
— количество элементов в массиве (1≤N≤100). Далее через пробел записаны N
чисел — элементы массива. Массив состоит из целых чисел.
Выходные данные
Необходимо вывести все элементы массива с чётными номерами.
Пример:
Ввод:
     6
     4 5 3 4 2 3
Вывод:
     4 3 2

Мой вариант (не рабочий):
n = int(input())
array=[0] * n
for i in range(len(array)):
    array[i] = map(int,input().split())
for i in range(len(array)):
    if i % 2 == 0:
         result = " ".join(array[i])
         print(result, end=' ')


Да небось не твой вариант, а чатгпт написал, поэтому ты и не можешь понять, что не так, потому что не знаешь вообще, что этот код делает.. Ты запрашиваешь ввод строки n раз! А ее вводят всего один раз.


map(int,input().split()) запрашивает весь список, не нужно его запрашивать n раз,

нам не нужен список чисел, так что map(int,input().split()) можно заменить на input().split()

функции join нужно передавать массив, а не один элемент,

не надо выводить ответ каждый раз.



спасибо большое!

@Miwar, «спасибо» здесь выражается принятием ответа (клик на галочку налево от него). См. Что делать с ответами на вопрос?
